# Mysql Full Outer Join Temporary Tables

Tags: mysql, join, temp-tables

There are a lot of questions about full-joining in mysql(5.1.36). Of course the solution is the join-union combination.

My problem is that I have two **temporary tables** like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE wConfs
(
    idWorker INT,
    confs SMALLINT
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE wRejects
(
    idWorker INT,
    rejects SMALLINT
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

JOIN-UNION mix cannot be used to full join temporary tables, because it will result in `ERROR 1137 (HY000): Can't reopen table`.

My question is - what is the simpliest solution with best performance to achieve full join on temporary tables?

**EDIT**:
JOIN-UNION mix:

```
SELECT wc.idWorker, wc.confs, wr.rejects FROM wConfs wc LEFT JOIN wRejects wr 
ON (wr.idWorker = wc.idWorker)
UNION
SELECT wc.idWorker, wc.confs, wr.rejects FROM wConfs wc RIGHT JOIN wRejects wr 
ON (wr.idWorker = wc.idWorker);
```

Comment: Where is the code of this "JOIN-UNION mix"?

Comment: Added this mix to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to create third temporary table with distinct `idWorker` values from two tables, then use it in your JOIN-UNION mix, e.g. -

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE all_id
  SELECT idWorker FROM wConfs UNION SELECT idWorker FROM wRejects;

SELECT t.idWorker, c.confs, r.rejects FROM all_id t
LEFT JOIN wConfs c
  ON t.idWorker = c.idWorker
LEFT JOIN wRejects r
  ON t.idWorker = r.idWorker;
```

Comment: The results table is kind of oakward, it has following columns `| idWorker | idWorker | confs | idWorker | rejects |`.

Comment: It is not a problem. Specify the fields you need instead of '*'. I have changed answer.

Comment: It has all fields I need, even more ;)  It should have only one `idWorker` column.

Comment: Specify the fields you need in SELECT list.

Comment: Haven't noticed you edited this yesterday. Sorry. Thx for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another way to solve it. I also created 3rd temp table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wResults;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE wResults
(
    idWorker INT PRIMARY KEY,
    rejects SMALLINT,
    confs SMALLINT
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Now I Insert rows to it like that:

```
INSERT INTO wResults(idWorker, confs)
    SELECT idWorker, confs FROM wConfs;

INSERT INTO wResults(idWorker, rejects)
    SELECT wr.idWorker, wr.rejects FROM wRejects wr
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rejects = wr.rejects;
```

It works like a charm. I guess that if there were a lot of data to insert - it would be pretty slow, but my tables are rather small.
Thank you all anyway!